# Load sharing MOSFET selection

Tags: mosfet, load

I have 3S series Li-Ion batteries and load sharing circuit. Like this [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01149c.pdf)
Sorry one-cell is shown in the figure but I have three-cell battery instead of one.
How can I specify suitable P-channel MOSFET?

1. As I know Vgs(th) value for the most MOSFETs is about between -2 and -4 V. When power supply is absent Vg=0V and Vs>8.4V so I shouldn't worry for Vgs(th) parameters, right? MOSFET can stays turned-ON state in any case.
2. I'll select a MOSFET with as low as Rds value. Continuous load current is about 300 mA, does this current can cause a over-heat problem while using a mosfet like IRF4905? Or this TO-263 package MOSFET too much luxury, SOT23 case will something work for me?
   What parameters of MOSFETs should I consider?

[image]

Comment: 1. What is the lowest Vgs your circuit needs to operate with? 2. Calculate how much power it will dissipate and check the Rth thermal resistance to ambient for each. How much temp rise can you live with?

Comment: 1) I only don't want to turn-off mosfet when battery powered state 2) Maybe 10 cantigrat live with.

Comment: That didn’t answer 1. As for 2, cool, now you can compute backwards what Rth and Rdson you need to satisfy that requirement.